# Do we welcome questions about problems with websites with past spam record?

Tags: discussion, spam

The SmokeDetector bot just caught [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52185367) two days ago with a moderate "confidence of being a real spam" (99%+). The domain contained in the post was matched by a partial RegEx and the question looked fine on its own. I even checked the website to ensure that the question was not "plagiarized + spam link", and was glad to find out that the CSS in the question was actually employed by the website.

While the question is innocent and appears all well except for being of low-quality (now closed), the domain doesn't look all that friendly. In fact, [that domain](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/domains/6065) had four ([1](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/39227) [2](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/73693) [3](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/73957) [4](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/74796)) past spam records on other Stack Exchange sites. What's more, when visiting the website, I recalled my familiarity with all characteristics of the typical fake tech-support site that spammed us - the gorgeous banner and motto, the huge "Call us now" heading, and the bloat-y advertisement.

Do we welcome questions from such parties or affiliations?

Comment: Curious about "e a volte vincono gli errori" (and sometimes errors win) at the end of the post.

Comment: @VincenzoC Random rant. That specific post has caused (and is still causing) some trouble with the SmokeDetector project.

Comment: @iBug I have removed it, since it's very unclear what you actually mean (even if I know Italian), I think we can do without it.

Comment: How can you have questions from a website?

Comment: `past spam record != malicious code`, voting to reopen.

Answer (score 19):

Yes. For all we know, it's a new owner with a new site. Judge the question by its own merit (including value to future visitors); this is yet another incarnation of "vote for the content, not for the user".

Of course, if it's a genuine question but the link is not relevant, edit it out, just like you would do if it hasn't been spammed before. A question should contain all necessary information in the question itself; an MCVE can by definition not rely on an external link.

Comment: Tempted to edit out the link now, but will leave it until this discussion is resolved.

Comment: What do you think about formatting the link as code?, this make it less click bait and no information is not lost.

Comment: *For all we know, it's a new owner with a new site.* I disagree. The website still looks like a typical fake tech support scam at the time of the question asked. The only thing is that the CSS in the question is genuine.

Comment: Still, it can be a new (but scam) site. And I'm trying to answer the question in general, not specifically focused on this site/question.

Answer (score 8):

Posting questions which happen to be about an unsavory site is fine. So long as the problem description can stand on its own (as all questions should try to do!), the fact that it happens to be occurring on this site is irrelevant.

Posting a vague, undebuggable description of a problem, *and linking to the scam website it's supposedly affecting* is not fine. Given the site's history, it is altogether too likely that the question is simply a more advanced attempt at getting the link to not be deleted.

The post has been deleted.

Comment: I have no accurate idea about the quality of the question - it's just slightly below the "salvageable" threshold IMO. But the CSS posted in the question *does* belong to the linked website. I checked it from F12 Developer Console.

Comment: @iBug I'm pretty sure that's just part of the ruse: post a question about a spammy site, and include a bit of random code from the site to make it look on-topic. The question doesn't really make any sense in context of that CSS snippet, when you consider it more closely -- the only tenuous connection is the `font-size: 100%` rule, which is part of the Meyer CSS reset and wouldn't cause the problem described in the question text.

Answer (score 7):

We welcome honest websites.

This one is unlikely to be one as:

1. They can't spell their own name:
   [image]
2. Their visual identity is incorrect (see official logo on every page of https://www.garmin.com or https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garmin)
3. They are in English only, while Garmin official website supports a lot of languages (French, German, Finnish, Dutch, Spanish, Italian, Polish, Simplified Chinese, Traditional Chinese, etc.): https://www.garmin.com/en-US/digital

And I'm sure there are many more issues.

This website has more than a *past* record of spam: **it is still currently a dangerous misleading website**.